# Routing from view (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

What would the best way be to achieve on the fly routing?  For example, on each view there would be a variable called "url", and that would be its route.

A view would look similar to:

```
<?php
$url = "about";
?>
@extends('layouts.main')
...
@stop
```

I was thinking the app could somehow iterate through the views and compile an array of all views and their variables (such as 'url', etc.).  The main route would be a wildcard, and would return the view of the associated URL.

What would be the best way to efficiently loop through the views to compile this list once (and possibly caching/storing in a database) without unnecessarily scanning multiple times?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking for is actually available in Laravel 5, which isn't currently released. Each method in a controller (not view) can be annotated with a route in one line of code, and you run an in-built scanner to find all of the routes. But this is mostly just FYI, I don't know of any existing package to do it in Laravel 4.*, and I don't really think the view is the correct place to do it.

Comment: You could compile a list into a file. Then your application would check if the file exists and load the routes from there. When the file does not exist it would scan all views once. Downside is that whenever a view gets updated, the file which hold the cached routes must be deleted first. Though as mentioned in Laravel 5 there will be a similar method in the controllers by using annotations.